# VB.Net Regular Expressions - Escape Method

Tags: regex, vb.net, escaping

Is there a way to escape all metacharacters in a string with the exception of "*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `Regex.Escape(str).Replace("\*", "*")`.

If the original string contains `\*`, this won't work properly.